# Docker Container Import-Module ServerManager issue

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, server, containers

Why when I run the below Windows OS docker image, I cannot run Import-Module ServerManager (error screen attached). I see that this module is missing from the modules list and the only way to add it is by installing RSAT tools which is only for windows 10 images. But what I am using is Windows OS server image.

docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows:ltsc2019
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLWWf.png)
the PowerShell I am using is 64 bit. Unless I have the ServerManager installed, I cannot install windows features and other things. Any help appreciated!

Installed docker desktop
pulled image mcr.microsoft.com/windows:ltsc2019
docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows:ltsc2019

Now, want to install PS module ServerManager.